# Is there a 2.72 equivalent to 'no caustics'?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, light

This image is quite hard to see due to heavy caustics, however, I haven't had to render in Cycles since *Blender 2.72* came out, and I can't for the life of me find '**no caustics**'.

I tried un-checking the two boxes that looked like they took it's place, but that didn't seem to change anything.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like this option was changed a bit. You can enable/disable caustics from reflections and from refraction (when light goes through transparent materials) separatly.

Just disable "Reflective Caustics" and "Refractive Caustics" in the Light Paths tab of the render settings.

[image]

**UPDATE:**

It seems that these settings do not work if you are using `Branched Path Tracing`. You can however play around with the `Clamp Indirect` value to trunkate high light values produced by reflected light.

[image]

Comment: I got no change. is there anything else?

Comment: When I tested it disabling reflective caustitcs reduced the noise created by rough glossy surfaces effectively. You can also try to increase the `Filter Glossy` value beneath the checkboxes. Otherwise I think you can only increase the number of samples.

Comment: You can find the sampling settings in the `Sampling` tab (usually 2nd tab above `Light Paths`). If you are using normal Path Tracing you can set the samples for the 3D viewport preview and the final render, if you are using Branched Path Tracing the options become a lot more dificult.

Comment: I found out that for Branched Path Tracing the light paths settings seem to have no influence. I updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: Yeah I don't know what the deal is, I put sampling up to 150, disabled everything, used integrator presets, pumped filter glassy as high as i could, but nothing helped. Also I can't upload pasteall is dead. Sorry folks, i'll accept anywho.

Comment: @VinceScalia I am sorry to hear that. But if Pasteall works again I would still be interrested in the .blend. And from my experience I would sag that 150 samples is usually not enough to get a clean render, even without caustics. For the final render I would rather go up to 1000 to 2000 samples.

Comment: Yeah got it working at 2500 then got kicked from my computer by a room-mate. Now i'm at a campus PC so I don't have a .blend, but i'm just about to put the render in this Meta post: http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/questions/545/awesome-weapons-challenge-2